# Find real zeroes where coefficients are not integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Suppose my equation is 
    $$f(x) = x^3 + 19.5x^2 -1021x + 999.5$$
I cannot use the rational zeros theorem since my coefficients are not integers.  What is the first step, and would I then follow with factoring this to a quadratic, from where I can find all real zeros?

Edits: 1. I understand that the equation has at most 3 roots; I understand that it has 1 negative root and either 0 or 2 positive roots. I also factored 2f(x) before I got here. My question is what are the steps I should follow? At least, the comment about factoring out the fractions is a step. Knowing that all roots are irrational is information, but I have one tool for figuring that, and it assumes I can find a rational root and then factor this to a quadratic.  What do I do when I can't (no, don't tell me it has 3 roots, tell me the steps, or at least a next step).

Comment: 2*f(x) has integer coefficients.

Comment: Your equation has three real roots.

Comment: use the Cadano formuals or do you Need approximativ Solutions?

Comment: As hjr said, $2f(x)= 2x^3+ 39x^2- 2042x+  1999= 0$  has integer coefficients.  But all the "rational zeros" theorem tells you is that this equation has NO rational roots.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg that in no way addresses my question.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Cardano formulas are not taught in algebra II (or at least not yet).

Comment: @user247327 thank you for providing information relevant to my question.  When you say the Rational Zeros theorem tells me there's no rational roots, is that because when I factor out p/q, and plug in the potential zeros, I find out that none of them work, or is there a test that saves me the step?

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite our equation in the following form:
$$(2x+13)^3-4591(2x+13)+65482=0$$ and since $\Delta=\frac{p^3}{27}+\frac{q^2}{4}<0$, our equation has three real roots,

which we can calculate by trigonometry.

Comment: When I get to trig next year, I'll let you know how much I like this answer.  That's why I specified algebra and edited the question to reflect the level of algebra I'm currently learning.  If I remember my calculus from 40 years ago, I bet that I could get there with calc too, but that's not the class I'm currently reviewing.

Comment: Good luck, @Ron!

Answer (score 1):

If you add $1$ to your polynomial you get

$$x^3+19.5x^2 - 1021x+1000.5 = (x-1)(x-23)(x+43.5).$$

The roots of your polynomial are really close, then, to $1, 23, $ and $-43.5.$

Comment: Thanks, this is a good tip, and I'll watch for that.  I found the irrational answers by finding lower and upper bounds, graphing and saw that I had three zeros very near the points you identified then used my graphing utility to find the actual zeros, which of course are irrational numbers.